# convert string to decimal before update a table or insert data into table

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ado.net

I'd like to ask you how to convert a string into a decimal before update a table or insert data into table, after a user inserts a row, or update a row from a dataGridView.

**For example,** I put a decimal value `2.2` to the price column, then I save it to the database, then I refreshed the table, the value is `2`, not the `2.2`, or add `2.8`, then the table shows us `3`, not `2.8`.

In my case, I want the column of price to be decimal, I do it as following, but it is not work, please help, thanks.

In form1.css:

```
..............
         //after a user click the save button
         private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
         { 
             Infor.UpdateDataSet((DataSet)dataGridView1.DataSource); 
          }
.........
```

Infor.css

```
  pInsert[3] = new SqlParameter("@p4", SqlDbType.Decimal, 40,
                                "price");
  pUpdate[2] = new SqlParameter("@p4", SqlDbType.Decimal, 40,
                                "price");
```

.........

```
   public static void UpdateDataSet(DataSet ds)
   {
      SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

      string sqlInsert, sqlUpdate, sqlDelete;
      sqlInsert = "insert into customers(customerid,companyname,
         contactname,price) values(@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4)";
      sqlUpdate = "update customers set companyname=@p2,
         contactname=@p3,price=@p4 where customerid=@p1";
      sqlDelete = "delete from customers where customerid=@p1";

      SqlParameter[] pInsert = new SqlParameter[4];
      SqlParameter[] pUpdate = new SqlParameter[4];
      SqlParameter[] pDelete = new SqlParameter[1];

      pInsert[0] = new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.VarChar,  5,
                                    "CustomerID");
      pInsert[1] = new SqlParameter("@p2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40,
                                    "CompanyName");
      pInsert[2] = new SqlParameter("@p3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40,
                                    "ContactName");
      pInsert[3] = new SqlParameter("@p4", SqlDbType.Decimal, 40,
                                    "price");

      pUpdate[0] = new SqlParameter("@p2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40,
                                    "CompanyName");
      pUpdate[1] = new SqlParameter("@p3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40,
                                    "ContactName");
      pUpdate[2] = new SqlParameter("@p4", SqlDbType.Decimal, 40,
                                    "price");
      pUpdate[3] = new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.VarChar,  5,
                                    "CustomerID");

      pDelete[0] = new SqlParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.VarChar,  5,
                                    "CustomerID");

      SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert,cnn);
      SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdate,cnn);
      SqlCommand cmdDelete = new SqlCommand(sqlDelete,cnn);

      cmdInsert.Parameters.AddRange(pInsert);
      cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddRange(pUpdate);
      cmdDelete.Parameters.AddRange(pDelete);

      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
      da.InsertCommand  = cmdInsert;
      da.UpdateCommand  = cmdUpdate;
      da.DeleteCommand  = cmdDelete;
      da.Update(ds, "customers");
      ds.AcceptChanges();
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

A decimal has two factors, scale and precision.

Precision is the number of digits that the number can contain.

Scale is the number of decimal places.

Examples

- 1111.**111**     (precision:  7, scale **3**)
- 11.**11111**     (precision:  7, scale **5**)

You have not denoted a scale when creating the parameter<strike>, only a precision</strike> (edit:  you're actually specifying size in bytes in the constructor, not precision).  You need to set the Precision and Scale properties explicitly to attain the result you are aiming for.

Example

*Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale.aspx.*

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("Price", SqlDbType.Decimal);
parameter.Value = 3.1416;
parameter.Precision = 8;
parameter.Scale = 4;
```

Pertinent note from the above source:

> Data may be truncated if the Scale property is not explicitly
>   specified and the data on the server does not fit in scale 0 (the
>   default).

The same applies to the column definition in the table, the precision and scale must also be specified and, of course, match.  *(Added following comment from @OlivierJacot-Descombes)*

Comment: Yes and the table column must of cause have an appropriate scale  as well. `CREATE TABLE customers (..., price DECIMAL(10, 2), ...)`

Comment: Agreed and upvoted @OlivierJacot-Descombes, adding to the answer.

Comment: @Kam2012 No worries, glad to help.  If this was the correct answer or helped you, please mark as the answer.

Comment: Hello; i got some error message now, "System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=Parameter value '11.000' is out of range.
  Source=System.Data".              pInsert[3] = new SqlParameter("@p4", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "Price");
            pInsert[3].Scale = 3; could you tell me why, please

Comment: @Kam2012 That's because you're not specifying the Precision as used by the example above.  This also defaults to 0.  Try setting the Precision property too.  I realise I made a mistake in the answer saying that you had specified the Precision, it's actually the Size which is the bytes storage size not the number of digits.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: pInsert[3] = new SqlParameter("@p4", SqlDbType.Decimal, 18, "Price"); pInsert[3].Precision = 18; pInsert[3].Scale = 3; How about the Value = ?, and the compiler ask me Must declare the scalar variable "@p3", and how to declare @p3?